# Nested dictionary to pandas DataFrame -

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My nested JSON -

Instance1 [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.03}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.37}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 58.84},, 'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]

Instance2 [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 60}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 55.45}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 54.16}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-06 07:50:00.000000', 'value': 50.03}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-04 22:50:00.000000', 'value': 60}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-26 01:50:00.000000', 'value': 60.34}, 'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]

Instance3 [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 60}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 38.12}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 42.31}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-06 07:50:00.000000', 'value': 45.22}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-04 22:50:00.000000', 'value': 40.51}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-26 01:50:00.000000', 'value': 34.35}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-11 12:50:00.000000', 'value': 46.33},'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]

And many more instance details to follow ( Close to 8K instance information )

I called the following function to de-normalize my nested JSON :

def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
df = df.reset_index()  # Reset index & sets a list of integer ranging from 0 to length of data as index.
s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all() # To check if all the values are true as list
list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

```
s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()


while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
    new_columns = []

    for col in dict_columns:
        horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
        horiz_exploded.index = df.index
        df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
        new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

    for col in list_columns:
        #print(f"exploding: {col}")
        df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
        new_columns.append(col)

    s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
return df
```

and followed by flatten_nested_json_df(df)

Coding work fine first 10 lines of my dataframe.
Eg- Less_metric= met_data_aug.iloc[:10,:] flatten_nested_json_df(Less_metric) # Parsing works at all layer and extracting all columns

Output :
_id metrics.metric  metrics.unit    metrics.datapoints.statistic    metrics.datapoints.timestamp    metrics.datapoints.value
0   612e09dd3d2001b69bd0dad1    VolumeIdleTime  Seconds Minimum 2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000  59.03
0   612e09dd3d2001b69bd0dad1    VolumeIdleTime  Seconds Minimum 2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000  59.37
0   612e09dd3d2001b69bd0dad1    VolumeIdleTime  Seconds Minimum 2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000  58.84
0   612e09dd3d2001b69bd0dad1    VolumeIdleTime  Seconds Minimum 2021-08-06 07:50:00.000000  59.41
0   612e09dd3d2001b69bd0dad1    VolumeIdleTime  Seconds Minimum 2021-08-04 22:50:00.000000  59.37
0   612e09dd3d2001b69bd0dad1    VolumeIdleTime  Seconds Minimum 2021-08-26 01:50:00.000000  57.21
0   612e09dd3d2001b69bd0dad1    VolumeIdleTime  Seconds Minimum 2021-08-11 12:50:00.000000  59.43

If i select 1000 lines :
Eg- med_metric= met_data_aug.iloc[:1000,:] or if i choose random line
ran_metric =met_data_aug.sample(10)

flatten_nested_json_df(med_metric) or flatten_nested_json_df(ran_metric)  # It is not parsing fully and not extracting all columns data .

```
index   metrics.metric  metrics.unit    metrics.datapoints
```

0   13445   VolumeIdleTime  Seconds {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-07 18:40:00.000000', 'value': 59.98}
0   13445   VolumeIdleTime  Seconds {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-14 08:40:00.000000', 'value': 59.99}
0   13445   VolumeIdleTime  Seconds {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-13 06:40:00.000000', 'value': 59.99}
0   13445   VolumeIdleTime  Seconds {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-19 20:40:00.000000', 'value': 59.98}
0   13445   VolumeIdleTime  Seconds {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-26 10:40:00.000000', 'value': 59.98}

Any NAN values or columnar difference on instances makes the coding to break ?

How to fix this issue ?- Please guide !!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC what you need is `json_normalize`. Set `datapoints`as `record_path` and `metric` and `unit` as `meta`:

```
data = [{'datapoints': [{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.03},{'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000', 'value': 59.37}, {'statistic': 'Minimum', 'timestamp': '2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000', 'value': 58.84}],'metric': 'VolumeIdleTime', 'unit': 'Seconds'}]
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path="datapoints", meta=["metric", "unit"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  statistic                   timestamp  value          metric     unit
0   Minimum  2021-08-31 06:50:00.000000  59.03  VolumeIdleTime  Seconds
1   Minimum  2021-08-18 02:50:00.000000  59.37  VolumeIdleTime  Seconds
2   Minimum  2021-08-24 16:50:00.000000  58.84  VolumeIdleTime  Seconds
```

Comment: Hi Tranbi,
Thanks for taking time to address my issue . I tried to same to apply on my nested JSON . But i receive the following error

"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: 250         # GH 31507 GH 30145, GH 26284 if result is not list, raise TypeError if not
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py in _pull_field(js, spec)
    237                 result = result[field]
    238         else:
--> 239             result = result[spec]
    240         return result
    241 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Is it different fron the one I used in my answer? Could you post your json in your question?

Comment: @SathishKumar how does this not answer the question? Please provide details about the problem you're facing (formatted in the question, otherwise hard to read as comment)